# Where is the midspan airfoil located on the 737?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, airfoil

The 737 has a root airfoil, two midspans, and one outboard. Is the midspan located under the fuselage or between root and tip?

Comment: You don't need an airfoil under the fuselage. "midspan" is between the root and the tip as the name suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The midspan airfoil is between root and tip, so somewhere along the *half* span of the wing. Midspan is therefore a misnomer, but sounds better than midhalfspan.